# Rails - automated migrations and seeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In my initializers folder I have a file with some ruby code which will perform a migration if a flag is set to true (for that environment)

```
if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
        Log.info 'Starting Migrations.'
        ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate "db/migrate"
```

Once a migration has finished, I want to run my seed file which is reference data.

```
 seed_file = File.join('db/seeds.rb')
        load(seed_file) if File.exist?(seed_file)
        Log.info 'Seed data loaded'
```

But will this run after the migration has ran?  i.e. will the migration complete before the seed starts?  Or do you need to check that the migration has finished?

I just want to make sure a migration will be completed before the seed runs.

note: this is rails running on windows and deployed with JRuby. Note that we use warbler to create a war file for deployment

Comment: Do you want to run migrations and seed every time Rails is loaded?

Comment: I guess every time we do a deployment to the environment, we want to run the migrations and then run the seeds.  I'm not sure if there is any issue with this?

Comment: The default way to do that is running `rake db:migrate` after deploy and before application starts. If you do that on initializers every time the application is loaded the initializers will run. When you start the application server each process will execute this, when console starts, etc.

Comment: does it have to be a manual task?  I am looking to automate this.  The application is started after a deployment I assume, so it should be ok for initializers to run.  But migration needs to be completed before seed starts, in case there is schema changes.
what is the correct way to automate this?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a manual task. Do you know the gem Capistrano? It's the best tool to run the deploy and execute all tasks you need before or after the deploy. Imagine you create an admin users using seed. If you put that code on initializer, every time your application is loaded a new admin user will be created.

Comment: Our deployments are automated using Bamboo, but I'll look into Capstrano.  For now, is there a way to ensure the migration completes before the seed is ran?

Comment: I'm sorry but I won't help you to continue with that because doesn't make sense.

Comment: I haven't tried Bamboo but any worthwhile continuous deployment software  should have deployment hooks. Check the triggers part https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo

Comment: Everything is packaged in a WAR file and pushed to the cloud, so I'm not sure how to run migrate and seed automatically, except using the initializers folder.  But how to ensure migrate has finished before seeds start?